# Render image from WordPress post content in Gatsby Single Post

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When I render a post content form Wordpress inside my Gatsby blog, the image keeps the same remote url.

[image]

How can I solve This? All other fetched images from ACF, Featured img, etc is working great.

my post.js component inside Gatsby:

```js
*imports......*

const postTemplate = ({ data: { post } }) => (
  <Layout>   
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row" style={{ marginBottom: '40px' }}>
        <PostSidebar
          date={post.date}
          author={post.author.name}
          categories={post.categories}
        />
        <PostContent className="col-lg-9">
          <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.title }} />
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />
        </PostContent>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Layout>
)

postTemplate.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default postTemplate

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    post: wordpressPost(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      content
      author {
        name
      }
      date(formatString: "DD, MMMM, YYYY",  locale: "pt")
      categories {
        id
        name
        slug
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: What versions of `gatsby-source-wordpress` are you running?

Comment: Hi! "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^5.3.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some GitHub threads, using uploaded WYSYWIG images was not supported by `gatsby-source-wordpress` until version +4:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11179
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3733
- https://github.com/TylerBarnes/gatsby-wordpress-inline-images: This plugin was created to bypass this limitation of posts content

Version 4 was released on 2021/02/04 according to the [`CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/CHANGELOG.md#410-next1-2021-02-04) and, according to the date of the post (2020/09/30), your issue should be fixed uploading your plugin's version.